# _PageStart.cshtml vs _AppStart.cshtml in ASP.NET WebPages

Tags: webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

What is the difference between _PageStart.cshtml vs _AppStart.cshtml? Can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

_AppStart.cshtml is executed once when the application first starts. It is the place for setting global variables, or configuring email etc. _PageStart.cshtml executes every time a page in the same or lower level folder is requested. It is the place for performing per-request processing, such as setting layout pages or denying access to a folder to unauthenticated users.

[See this article at the Microsoft Web Pages site](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior).

Since they execute at different times in the application's lifecycle, it's difficult to see how they can be used interchangeably, whatever you mean by that.

Comment: I thought they're the same. Thanks!